# Paragraph delimiters that disappear at the tops and bottoms of pages (like \vspace)

Tags: spacing

Books of poetry, or collections of short prose expressions, are often delimited by ornaments. I would like a command that inserts an ornament between paragraphs, but that disappears at the top or bottom of a page. That way I don't have to insert the ornaments manually when I'm typesetting a large collection. (I'm thinking of how `\vspace` automatically goes away at the top of the page.) In the MWE below, the third delimiter would ideally just disappear, since it would be at the top of a page.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,bottom=4.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,pgfornament}
\newcommand\MyDelimiter{\vspace{2em}\begin{center}\pgfornament[width=0.5*\textwidth]{86}\end{center}\vspace{2em}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\MyDelimiter

\lipsum[1]

\MyDelimiter

\lipsum[1]

\MyDelimiter % this one should just disappear

\lipsum[1]

\MyDelimiter

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

By the same token, the delimiter should disappear if it's the last thing on a page:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,bottom=10.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,pgfornament}
\newcommand\MyDelimiter{\vspace{2em}\begin{center}\pgfornament[width=0.5*\textwidth]{86}\end{center}\vspace{2em}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\MyDelimiter

\lipsum[1]

\MyDelimiter % this one should just disappear

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly what you mean, there’s a famous trick, due to Marcin Woliński, based on the use of `\leaders`.  I haven’t time to post an answer now, but if you can read Italian, I’ll refer to [this possibly related answer](http://www.guitex.org/home/forum/5-tex-e-latex/98601-tre-asterischi?lang=en#100834) appeared ont the [Italian Tug](http://www.guitex.org/).

Comment: Here’s an English reference, too: [How to make a box disappear at a line break](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/pearls/2007p/index_html).

Comment: Great, thanks! I've used that macro in my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want no separator between items at the top and bottom of the pages. The `memoir` class has a set of macros related to this which might be worth looking at (in the user manual section "Fancy Anonymous Breaks" `texdoc memoir`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a MWE with the delimiter disappearing at the end of a page. The macro definition follows [this link](http://www.guitex.org/home/en/forum/5-tex-e-latex/98601-tre-asterischi), which was suggested in the comments (thanks Gustavo Mezzetti!).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,bottom=14cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,pgfornament}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\MyDelimiter{\par
  % Emulate LaTeX's \bigbreak (more or less):
  \ifdim\lastskip<\bigskipamount
    \removelastskip
  \fi
  \penalty -200
  % Do not depend on e-TeX's \glueexpr:
  \skip@ \medskipamount
  \multiply \skip@ \tw@
  \advance \skip@ \baselineskip
  \dimen@ \skip@
  \advance \dimen@ -8\p@
  \cleaders \vbox to \dimen@ {%
    \vss
    \centerline{%
      \vrule \@height 10\p@ \@depth\tw@\p@ \@width \z@
      \pgfornament[width=0.5*\textwidth]{86}
    }%
    \vss
  }\vskip \skip@
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\MyDelimiter

\lipsum[1]

\MyDelimiter % this one should just disappear

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

I don't follow all of the code but I note that the vertical spacing can be adjusted by adding to `\skip@`, e.g., by replacing:

```
\advance \skip@ \baselineskip
```

With:

```
\advance \skip@ \baselineskip
\advance \skip@ \baselineskip
\advance \skip@ \baselineskip
```